# put label on node in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to put label on any node, 
I plot  nodes with  its edges  with

```
gplot(adjacencyM,[A(1:2:end)',A(2:2:end)'],'-*');
```

and result is 
[image]

**how can I put label on nodes? like 1 ,2,3 ,4 ,5,...**

`A=[52.4804497434472    27.6195191737248    4.21212076867730    30.4259790113270    48.7710166342266    39.0235130272618    77.6293705126495    27.8870044967533    8.53744606710097    96.9598745936163    17.0082513400534    1.22018736621158    45.2910471948658    19.6246954290650    32.3671095309084    46.6923831457201    52.0721582460992    13.2199644010638    9.61840162265927    40.9950628287157
]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  [Matlab's `text` command](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html)
For example:

```
text( A(1,1), A(1,2), 'Label first node');
```

or in a loop:

```
for li=1:2:numel(A)
    text( A(li), A(li+1), sprintf('<--%d', li) );
end
```